# MIUI rom fails to install on HTC Desire

Tags: htc-desire, rom-flashing, miui

This is my first post, so apologies if I don't make things as clear as they should be. 
I'm trying to flash MIUI_0.8.1-2.9.7zip on HTC Desire. I'm doing this through goomanager. I wiped data, cache and dalvik cache and installed the zip from a sd card. While installing I get the following message on screen...

```
E:missing file
 system/media/audio/ringtones
 argonavis.ogg

E:verification failed
```

Then it aborts installation. Do I need to partition the sd card? If so, what would be the best way to partition it? Through Rom manager or Gparted? Currently I'm using MIUI GB version 2.3.7, I have S-ON
Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm doing this through goomanager.

First of all, you're rooted right? Also, this might seem obvious but I'm going to suggest it anyway: have you tried installing it through CWM Recovery? That seems to be the normal way to install/wipe ROMs, so I'd try that first. See [Howto: Using the Recovery](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Howto%3a_Using_the_Recovery).

Also, your ROM installation ZIP might be corrupt. Double check the md5 sum on it, if it doesn't match, try redownloading it. Try another ROM, might be a corrupt version of the ROM (if it's a nightly for example).

If you have any questions or additional details, comment and I'll update this answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time toreply, yeah the phone is rooted right, i have installed a number of different roms succesfully, i have tried to instal the ROM through CWM, i have downloaded and tried to install a few times but get the same error codes?? I did have cm10 ics ROM on the phone about a month ago, some how i bricked the sd card but i did manage to unbrick it, all is working ok now, do you think this could have anything to do with it?  please can you explain what md5 sum is, and what you mean by "nightly" many thanks again for your time.